# Getting a SIGABRT error on a new project

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I started getting a weird error in my project, so I created a whole new document-based project just to test (in Xcode 4). I added a 'Text View' to the Document.xib, and ran the program. I manage to open a few new documents, type some stuff in the text view, then I pause, and then the program terminates. It gives me: *"Program received signal "SIGABRT".*

The error is in the default document.m file, in method:

```
- (NSData *)dataOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
```

on line:

```
@throw exception
```

What's going on?

PS. I looked at the Activity Monitor, and all the loads: System Load, User Load, go way up all at once before it quits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> The default implementation of this method throws an exception because
>   at least one of the writing methods (this method,
>   writeToURL:ofType:error:, fileWrapperOfType:error:, or
>   writeToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:originalContentsURL:error:) must be
>   overridden.

My guess is that you didn't implement these method(s).  I also bet you're on Lion and have autosaving enabled (see +autosavesInPlace), and that the exception is thrown when the app tries to autosave after an internal timer / change watcher is triggered.